# How do I pass a cell at a time, e.g. (A1; B1; C1) or an array (A1:C1) to the same C function of Excel's XLL file?

Tags: excel, function, parameters, xll

I would like to pass the arguments to the function of two ways, as the Sum function in Excel does. eg. = SUM (A1, B1, C1) or SUM (A1: C1).

Either way, separately, I know.

1) Calc (double fstNum, double secNum, double thdNum, double fthNum)

2) Calc (xl_array p_array *)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be using the xloper12 type and check if the parameter is of type array, single value or empty.

```
*calc (xloper12* arg1, xloper12* arg2, xloper12* arg3){

double sum = 0;

// check first arg if empty
if (!(arg1->xltype & (arg1| xltypeNil))){   

    // check if arg is array
    if ( arg1->xltype == xltypeMulti){
        // for loop - summing the array values 
    } 
    // single value
    else {
        sum += arg1->val.num;
    }
}    
// check next arg and do the same
...
```

Answer (score -1):

It may help to think of SUM(...) as operating on ranges of cells:

SUM(Rg1, Rg2, Rg3, ... )

Then your two examples are: (a) 3 ranges of 1 cell each, and (b) 1 range of 3 cells.

[ In response to uncommented downvote. ]

Try

3) Calc (xl_array p_array1 *, xl_array p_array2 *, xl_array p_array3 *, xl_array p_array4 *)

Nothing (of course!) that these arrays can be 2 dimensional.